# iPhone dev: any snippet to resize an image and keep the ratio?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to developing code in iPhone, and I want to search some code to resize my UIImage to a specified size but keep the ratio. The specified size is something like a frame that the image can't come cross the boundary, within that boundary the image should scale to fit the frame and keep the ratio, the code I am currently using can do resize but can't keep the ratio, just paste it here to see if I can do some trivial modifications so that it can make it possible.

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Set the quality level to use when rescaling
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);  
// Draw into the context; this scales the image
CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

// Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

return newImage;
```

}

Comment: You can do that by setting property on UIImageView. Not sure about processing the UIImage itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well,  you could resize the image a bit simpler:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Then you need to calculate a new size that maintenance the aspect ratio. 
e.g. to get a image Half the size you would provide a size created like this:

```
  CGSize halfSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width*0.5, image.size.height*0.5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code for resizing images to specific boundaries while preserving aspect ratio:

```
imageSize // The image size, for example {1024,768}
boundarySize // The boundary to fit the image into, for example {960,640}

boundaryAspectRatio = boundarySize.width / boundarySize.height
imageAspectRatio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height

if ( imageAspectRatio == boundaryAspectRatio )
{
    // The aspect ratio is equal
    // Resize image to boundary
}
else if ( imageAspectRatio > boundaryAspectRatio )
{
    // The image is wider
    // Resize to:
    // - Width:   boundarySize.width
    // - Height:  boundarySize.height / imageAspectRatio
} 
else if ( imageAspectRatio < boundaryAspectRatio )
{
    // Resize to:
    // - Width:   boundarySize.width * imageAspectRatio
    // - Height:  boundarySize.height
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change MAX to MIN to Fit instead of Fill ;)

```
- (UIImage *)imageByFillingSize:(CGSize)newSize useScreenScale:(BOOL)useScreenScale
{
    CGSize size = [self size];
    CGRect frame;
    float ratioW = newSize.width / size.width;
    float ratioH = newSize.height / size.height;
    float ratio = MAX(ratioW, ratioH);

    frame.size.width = size.width * ratio;
    frame.size.height = size.height * ratio;
    frame.origin.x = (newSize.width - frame.size.width) / 2.0;
    frame.origin.y = (newSize.height - frame.size.height) / 2.0;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, useScreenScale ? 0.0 : 1.0);
    [self drawInRect:frame];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```