# UIImageView how to cut off Top and Bottom?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

My app load an Image in a DetailView. This Detailview is full of information, so I have to win some space. The Image i want to display is really small: `132 × 99` so i have to scale it to the whole width of the screen -> `320 x 240` this looks really big on the screen. So I want to cut the top and the bottom to get `320 x 150` without loosing aspect ratio. I tried: `Scale To Fill`, `Scale To Fit`, `Center`, `Aspect To Fill`, `Aspect To Fit`... in the IB. None was the right. Is there any programmatically way?

**EDIT**

there are some screenshots 
The source:
[image: original]
Storyboard:

[image: IB]
and the ugly version:

[image: streched]
my goal (photoshopped):
[image]

Comment: Please add some screenshot to clarify your question. Also, have you tried to change UIImageView's frame itself? Why to change an image if the drawing element has to be resized?

Comment: Check my Answer :http://stackoverflow.com/a/15894836/1603072 Just pass the Size (320,150).

Comment: @Vin it will result like my ugly screenshot.

Comment: i just added my goal as photoshopped screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a necessary size to UIImageView and set it content type to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill

```
Scales the content to fill the size of the view. 
Some portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.
```

**EDIT**

As i understand correctly - it works fine for me, see screenshot from IB:

[image]

[image]

[image] It's a property of UIImageView - it's important to select `Aspect Fill`, not `Scale To Fill`

And this work only for UIImageView (not UIButtons)

Comment: not working. It display the image exactly like `AspectFill` in the IB. It will result in `320 x 240` and not in `320 x 150`

Comment: You should set the frame to UIImageView, not to UIImage itself / not to work with content mode. Why to use a bigger frame of UIImageView for a small and only one image?

Comment: result:  http://666kb.com/i/cdn7q7k4v2tmg7kc8.jpg it will loose every defined image size and overlay eveything.

Comment: @Curtis Timo Schmidt - it is the space around imageView... the size of UIImageView the same as the image inside

Comment: Also you can set property Clip Subviews = YES (also in IB)